# Locally changing what \ref displays

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I want to write

> as will be shown in chapter 3 section [4.3](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Table_of_Conics%2C_Cyclopaedia%2C_volume_1%2C_p_304%2C_1728.jpg/250px-Table_of_Conics%2C_Cyclopaedia%2C_volume_1%2C_p_304%2C_1728.jpg),

where the hyperlink on ``4.3'' is generated by `\ref{sec: titleOfSec4.3}`. But this `\ref` of course gives me

> as will be shown in chapter 3 section [3.4.3](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Table_of_Conics%2C_Cyclopaedia%2C_volume_1%2C_p_304%2C_1728.jpg/250px-Table_of_Conics%2C_Cyclopaedia%2C_volume_1%2C_p_304%2C_1728.jpg),

which I find ugly as the first 3 is redundant and even possibly misleading (especially when the text is printed). Is there any way to change how \ref displays the reference to sections, i.e., to get rid of the superfluous 3 (i.e., the chapter counter)?

Comment: Why don't you just rephrase the text as `as will be shown in section \ref{sec: titleOfSec4.3},`, which returns you *as will be shown in section 3.4.3,*?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Yeah, that's what I actually did, but I'm a bit unhappy with that for indeterminate reasons, and I was just generally curious if its possible.

Comment: one thing that I can suggest you is to have a look at the `cleveref` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en
See section 8.2.1 *Single Cross-References*

Comment: As a reader I would be confused to see a reference to section 4.3 and it is not to be found, because it is actually section 3.4.3. As Alessandro mentioned above, I think it is more standard to explicitly write `... section 3.4.3` and not mention the chapter at all.

Comment: Related/duplicate? [How to reference the subsection number without the section number?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/503263). Also see the comments there on how such a system is not necessarily confusing to readers.